# How to create a file upload REST API controller for Yii2

Tags: php, api, ionic-framework, yii2

I am using Ionic framework for mobile app development. The Yii2 API code below can be used for file upload, but it doesn't work. It shows the following errors:

> i) Undefined offset: 0.
>
> ii) yii\db\BaseActiveRecord->save()

```
public function actionNew() {
    $model = new Apiprofile();
    $userid = $_REQUEST['user_id'];
    $photo = $_FILES['photo'];
    $model->user_id = $userid;
    $model->photo = $photo;
    $name = $model->user_id;
    $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'photo');

    if($model->file) {
        $model->file->saveAs('uploads/photos/'.$name.'.'.$model->file->extension);
        $model->photo = $name.'.'.$model->file->extension;
        $model->save();
    }

    $name = $model->user_id;

    if($model->save()) {
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>1,'data'=>$model->attributes),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>0,'error_code'=>400,'errors'=>$model->errors),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide full error message(s) as well as where (line number may be) it is showing?    
and btw why are you doing same thing twice: this `$model->photo` and this `$name` and this `$model->save()` !

Comment: First thank for your reply. Yes $name unnecessary for second time ,bt first $model->save(), save only photo, second one check other fields save or not,and first model->photo used to get input from user ,and second model->photo used to rename the file and save into db.

Comment: "C:\\Projects\\htdocs\\basic12\\controllers\\ApiprofileController.php(67): yii\\db\\BaseActiveRecord->save()",. this is our json format error

Comment: `Undefined offset: 0` error occurs when you try to access an array index which is not set. check `$_REQUEST['user_id']` and `$_FILES['photo']` before accessing them. you can use `isset()` method for that. see if that works

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you want I will share my helper class that I used for working with images in Yii2 REST.

In the base folder of your application create folder components and inside of that folder create two folders helpers and objects.

```
 -->assets
    -->componests
            ----->helpers
            ----->objects
    -->config
    -->...
```

after that create class FileUpload inside of objects folder and put this code inside.

```
<?php
namespace app\components\objects;


class FileUpload
{
    public $error=[];
    public $isSuccess=false;
    public $file;
    public $ready_path;
    public $file_type;
    public $file_size;
    public $file_extension;
    public $file_tmp_name;

    public $file_name;
    public $save_path;

    public function __construct($file,$save_path,$ready_path,$required=false)
    {
        if(!isset($_FILES[$file])){
            if($required){
                $this->error=['message'=>$file.' is required'];
            }
            return $this;
        }
        $this->save_path=$save_path;
        $this->ready_path=$ready_path;
        $this->file_type = strtolower($_FILES[$file]['type']);
        $this->file_name = $_FILES[$file]['name'];
        $this->file_tmp_name=$_FILES[$file]['tmp_name'];
        $this->file_size = $_FILES[$file]['size'];
        $this->file_extension=pathinfo($this->file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    }

    public function setError($error){
        if(empty($this->error)){
            $this->error=$error;
        }
    }

}
```

Then inside of helpers folder create class FileUploadHelper and then put this code inside.

```
<?php
namespace app\components\helpers;
use app\components\objects\FileUpload;
use Yii;

class  FileUploadHelper
{

    private $allowed_files;
    private $file_size;
    const IMAGE='image';
    const FILE='file';

    /** File Upload
     * @param string $file_name
     * @param string $save_path
     * @param string $ready_path
     * @param string $type
     * @param bool $required

     * @return \app\components\objects\FileUpload
     */
    public static function fileUpload($file_name,$save_path,$ready_path,$type,$required=false){

        $image=new FileUpload($file_name,$save_path,$ready_path,$required);
        if($type==self::FILE){
            $allowed_files=Yii::$app->params['allowed_files'];
            $file_size=Yii::$app->params['file_max_size'];
        }else{
            $allowed_files=Yii::$app->params['allowed_files'];
            $file_size=Yii::$app->params['file_max_size'];
        }
        $dir = realpath(Yii::$app->basePath);
        if(in_array($image->file_type,$allowed_files)
            &&$image->file_size<$file_size){
            $filename = $file_name.'_'.md5(uniqid(time()).time() . '_' . date('YmdHis')) . '.' . $image->file_extension;
            $file = $dir . $image->save_path . $filename;
            if(move_uploaded_file($image->file_tmp_name, $file)){
                $image->file=$image->ready_path. $filename;
                $image->isSuccess=true;
                $image->setError(['message'=>'file_upload_success']);
            }else{
                $image->setError(['message'=>'error_try_again']);
            }
        }else{
            $image->setError(['message'=>'file_should_be_no_more_than_given_size']);
        }
        return $image;
    }


    /** Delete File
     * @param string $ready_file
     */
    public static function deleteImage($ready_file){
        $dir = realpath(Yii::$app->basePath);
        if (strpos($ready_file, 'default') === false){
            if(is_file($dir.'/web/'.$ready_file)){
                unlink($dir.'/web/'.$ready_file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's all needed. Below I will give you example

```
public function actionEditAvatar($id)
    {
        $product = Product::findOne($id);
        if( $product ){
                $old_avatar=$product->avatar;
                $image=FileUploadHelper::fileUpload(ProductForm::AVATAR,Yii::$app->params['product_path'],Yii::$app->params['product_ready_path'],FileUploadHelper::IMAGE);
                if($image->isSuccess) {
                    $product->avatar = $image->file;
                    if($product->save()){
                        FileUploadHelper::deleteImage($old_avatar);
                        return $product->avatar;
                    }

                }
            return $image->error;
        }
        throw new NotFoundHttpException;
    }
```

The code above from a real project. FileUploadHelper has two static classes which are "fileUpload" and "deleteImage". 
FileUploadHelper requires fileUpload('file_name','save_path','ready_path','type')
'save_path' is where the file will be saved. 
'ready_path' is how the ready URL should be like.
they are in Yii::$app->params[];

You can check if image succeeded or not by attribute isSuccess. If you have the error you can access them by attribute error. The ready file can be accessed by attribute file. You can delete image via static function deleteImage('saved_image_url'); All of them are used at above action. Please see it. 
By the way, here the params that I used. Do not forget to to create folders inside web/uploads and change names of the folders like in config file.

```
return [
    'adminEmail' => 'admin@example.com',

    'allowed_images'                   => [ 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png' ],
    'allowed_files'                    => [ 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document','application/msword', 'application/pdf','image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png'],

    'image_max_size'                   => 2097152,
    'file_max_size'                    => 8388608,

    'owner_document_path'              => '/web/uploads/owner_document/',
    'owner_document_ready_path'        => 'uploads/owner_document/',

    'product_path'                     => '/web/uploads/product/',
    'product_ready_path'               => 'uploads/product/',

    'complain_photo_path'              => '/web/uploads/complain_photo/',
    'complain_photo_ready_path'        => 'uploads/complain_photo/',

    'owner_path'                       => '/web/uploads/owner/',
    'owner_ready_path'                 => 'uploads/owner/',


    'staff_path'                       => '/web/uploads/staff/',
    'staff_ready_path'                 => 'uploads/staff/',
];
```